Poincare residue and trivializing section of canonical bundle of plane cubic.
I am trying to get my hands dirty and do the following computation, but I don't feel like I'm doing it right. Help would be very much appreciated! I will tell you the setup of the calculation, and tell you which part I am struggling on. I am, in particular, struggling on well-definedness.
Let $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$ be a smooth plane cubic. Suppose for our calculation that it is cut out by the homogeneous degree 3 equation $F = Z_0^3 + Z_1^3 + Z_2^3$. We know that $\Omega_C = \omega_C \cong \mathcal{O}_C$. The point of the calculation is to actually demonstrate a trivialization section of $\Omega_C$. The claim is that it can be given by the Poincare residue of
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\Res\left(\frac{z_0 dz_1 \wedge dz_2 - z_1 dz_0 \wedge dz_2 + z_2 dz_0 \wedge dz_1}{z_0^3 + z_1^3 + z_2^3}\right),
$$
given by page 8 of Lectures on K3 surfaces by Daniel Huybrechts (or on the example section of Wikipedia entry on Poincare residue ). This is a bit of an abuse of notation. This notation is supposed to mean that, for example, on the distinguished open $(Z_0 \neq 0)$, with coordinates $x_1$ and $x_2$, we want to compute the residue
$$
\Res\left(\frac{dx_1 \wedge dx_2}{1 + x_1^3 + x_2^3}\right).
$$
Letting $\phi = 1+ x_1^3 + x_2^3$, from my calculation, I have that
$$
\frac{1}{3}[x_2 dx_1 - x_1 dx_2] \wedge \frac{d \phi}{\phi} + \frac{dx_1 \wedge dx_2}{\phi} = dx_1 \wedge dx_2,
$$
from which I conclude that the residue is $\frac{1}{3}[x_2 dx_1 - x_1 dx_2]$.
On the other hand, if I repeat this calculation for the distinguished open $(Z_1 \neq 0)$, given by coordinates $(y_0, y_1)$, where we have the isomorphism $(Z_0 \neq 0) \to (Z_1 \neq 0)$ defined by $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto \left(\frac{1}{x_1}, \frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)$, I find that
$$
\frac{1}{3}[y_2 dy_0 - y_0 dy_2] \wedge \frac{d \psi}{\psi} + \frac{dy_0 \wedge dy_2}{\psi} = dy_0 \wedge dy_2
$$
where $\psi = y_0^3 + 1 + y_2^3$. So then I conclude the residue is
$$
\Res\left(\frac{-dy_0 \wedge dy_2}{y_0^3 + 1 + y_2^3}\right) =  -\frac{1}{3}[y_2 dy_0 - y_0 dy_2].
$$
But when I do the change of coordinates from $(x_1, x_2)$ to $(y_0, y_2)$, I have
$$
dy_0 \mapsto d\left(\frac{1}{x_1}\right) = \frac{-dx_1}{x_1^2}\; \text{ and }\; dy_2 \mapsto d\left(\frac{x_1}{x_1}\right) = \frac{-x_2 dx_1 + x_1 dx_2}{x_1^2}.
$$
If I apply this, it looks like the residues don't agree with each other on overlaps. In particular,
$$
-\frac{1}{3}[y_2 dy_0 - y_0 dy_2] \mapsto -\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{x_1^2} dx_2.
$$
This is the part that I am confused about. What am I doing wrong?

The abusive notation is troubling.   I don't know what the distinction between $Z_j$ and $z_j$ is in that, and I don't see why this is a well-defined meromorphic form. The standard correct thing is to work in local coordinates and check that the definition is invariant. As far as I'm concerned, $$\text{Res}\left(\frac{dx_1\wedge dx_2}{1+x_1^3+x_2^3}\right) = \frac{dx_2}{3x_1^2} = -\frac{dx_1}{3x_2^2},$$ which you can check is well-defined on the curve.

Did you see the bottom half of my question? I clarified that the abuse of notation is indeed troubling, but I give the local definition. I've made the edits to show there is no distinction between $Z_j$ and $z_j$, apologies. My issue is this change of coordinates between the local calculations. The pullback of the residue I calculate on the distinguished open where $Z_1 \neq 0$ agrees with what you just wrote. But when I actually compute the residue on $Z_0 \neq 0$, I don't get what you claimed. So what went wrong?

Note that if we change charts from $(x_1,x_2)$ to $(y_1,y_2)$ with $y_1=1/x_1$ and $y_2=x_2/x_1$, then $\frac{dx_1\wedge dx_2}{1+x_1^3+x_2^3}$ changes indeed to $\frac{dy_1\wedge dy_2}{1+y_1^3+y_2^3}$ and $dy_1/y_2^3=-dx_1/3x_2^3$ and $dy_2/y_1^3=dx_2/x_1^3$, as forms on the curve.

Does the equality $dy_1/y_2^3 = -dx_1/3x_2^3$ here mean pull back of $dy_1/y_2^3$ is $-dx_1/3x_2^3$? If this is the case, I don't see why this is true. The pullback of $dy_1/y_2^3$ should be $d(1/x_1)/(x_2/x_1)^3 = -(x_1/x_2^3)dx_1$.

Calculate carefully. Where is the $dx_2$ term?

I made a weird typo in my comment but have updated it. I still don't see how the pullback of $dy_1/y_2^3$ is $-dx_1/3x_2^3$.

Sorry. I typed too quickly. The cubes in the denominators should be squares.
